# Python replace statement

Tags: python, linux, cpanel

I'm pretty new to Python but need to patch this glitch/exploit in an addon service.

My code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import yaml
from xml.dom import minidom
sys.path.append('/scripts')
import createvhosts
doc = minidom.parse(sys.stdin)

param0taglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('param0')
param1taglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('param1')
param0 = param0taglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
param1 = param1taglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()

domain = param0 + '.' + param1
usertaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('USER')
user = usertaglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
f = open('/var/cpanel/userdata/' + user + '/main')
ydata = yaml.load(f)
f.close()
sublist = ydata['sub_domains']
addondict = ydata['addon_domains']
parkedlist = ydata['parked_domains']
mainlist = ydata['main_domain']
serverip = createvhosts.getmainip()
if len(sublist) != 0:
    slcont = 0
    while slcont < len(sublist):
        domain = sublist[slcont]
        docroot, yip, alias = createvhosts.getvars(sublist[slcont])
        if yip == serverip:
            createvhosts.writeconfshared(user, domain, docroot, yip, alias)
        else:
            createvhosts.writeconfded(user, domain, docroot, yip, alias)
        slcont = slcont + 1
proc = subprocess.Popen("/etc/init.d/nginx restart > /dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
```

The issue is when you add a subdomain in CPanel with * it will crash the server because apparently nginx does not seem to allow and accept that. What I need help doing is figuring out how to replace/block * so it does not go in.

Does something like `Param0.find( "*" ) !=-1` work?

Comment: Please remove the extra code so that just a minimal test-case and question remains. Include code to build sample (e.g. failing) data if needed.

Comment: print `Param0.replace('*','')` ... its almost like you didnt try anything...

Comment: I'm thinking it might be more ideal to just block the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct you're looking for is `char in string`.

```
>>> s = 'ab*de'
>>> '*' in s
True
```

Put this in a conditional and you've got what you want - something like:

```
if '*' in param0:
    raise ValueError("Can't use '*'!")
```

This, along with a comprehensive list of the methods available on strings to do more involved work, is documented [in the official docs, under Built-in Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).